# Dynamically changing font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current code but as you see, whenever the font-size changes doe to the resizing of the browser width. The hover effect doesn't 1.5x the font-size, how can I make the hover effect dynamically take the current font-size of the text and double it up (1.5x) accordingly?

---->    https://jsfiddle.net/054yzoux/  <---------

html

```
    <nav class="navbar-menu">
    <ul id="list" class="test">
        <li id="emph nav-home">Home</li>
        <li id="nav-portfolio">Portfolie</li>
        <li id="nav-skills">Færdigheder</li>
        <li id="nav-erfaring">Erfaring</li>
        <li id="nav-kontakt">Kontakt mig</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
.navbar-menu ul li{
    display: block;
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.navbar-menu ul li:hover{
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(3%);
    background-color: #888888;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

**Issue**
To see what the issue is, increase the browser width, when in the jsfiddle and hover over the text. As you see the text decreases instead of increasing by 50%

Comment: have you tried to use scale instead of font-size: 2em ? EM is depending on default font size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is arising because for a fixed view, *maybe **4vw** is less than the **2em** on hover* that's why it is **enlarging the font**, but for larger views ***2em is smaller than 4vw*** that's why the **glitch effect**.

- *Instead of 2em* *(which will always be **same for all viewport** resolutions)*, **give a vw value** as well which is bigger than 4vw so maybe **5vw** *(this ensures that on hover, the new font-size will always be greater than the normal font-size since **5vw > 4vw** for all viewport resolutions)* and it works fine.
- Another point to note is that the **transition** should be provided o*n the **default state** of element*, not when a CSS selector is defined. This ensures that it will take place when the hover occurs as well as taken out.

```css
.navbar-menu ul li{
    display: block;
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin-top: 5%;
    transition:all 0.3s;
}

.navbar-menu ul li:hover{
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(3%);
    background-color: #888888;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-menu">
        <ul id="list" class="test">
            <li id="emph nav-home">Home</li>
            <li id="nav-portfolio">Portfolie</li>
            <li id="nav-skills">Færdigheder</li>
            <li id="nav-erfaring">Erfaring</li>
            <li id="nav-kontakt">Kontakt mig</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to double the size of font when hover, you should use 'em' unit for both initial and hover states.

The following code will work:

```
.navbar-menu ul li{
display: block;
font-size: 3em;
margin-top: 5%;}

.navbar-menu ul li:hover{
color: #fff;
transform: translateX(3%);
background-color: #888888;
transition-duration: 0.3s;
font-size: 4em;}
```

Comment: If you didn't understand the question then ask in the comments and changing from 'vw' to 'em' doesn't keep the responsiveness of the font anymore, try to add it into a snippet and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using animation (transformation), better to use same units for more accurate result.

```
.navbar-menu ul li{
    ...
    font-size: 4vw;
    ...
}

.navbar-menu ul li:hover{
    ...
    font-size: 6vw;/* will give 50% enlarge effect*/
    ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4vLac7we/).